# Copying section of map array

Tags: javascript, path-finding

I'm experimenting a bit with pathfinding. I'm using Javascript.

I have a map array as follows:

```
mapArray = [
             [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
             [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
             [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
           ];
```

The map is fairly excessive in size and I would like to take out a portion of it to pass to the pathfinding algo. How could I go about doing this? From the above, I could take out a section to leave this for instance:

```
mapArray = [
             [0, 1, 1],
             [0, 1, 0],
             [0, 1, 1],
           ];
```

Which would be copying from 0,2 through to 1,4 (xy).

My first thought was a for loop but it is failing for a reason I don't fully understand. Probably a misunderstanding of inserting into arrays?

```
var pathfindingMapArray = [];

for ( y = startRow; y < endRow; y++ ) {
    for ( x = startColumn; x < endColumn; x++ ) {

        pathfindingMapArray[y][x] = mapArray[y][x];
    }
}
```

The above fails as a TypeError.

Comment: If you're map is really large you will want to split it up further, basically a map of maps. Ideally those maps would be the right size for your pathfindind. And if you do a lot of pathfinding, the maps could overlap just a little so you don't have to get the next map part that often. The last bonus would of course be to store the calculated paths and try the most often used ones before calculating a new one. Your things might end up moving like ants, but maybe they are ants anyways ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and it seems to be working:

```js
var pathfindingMapArray = [];
for (y = startRow; y < endRow; y++) {
    var row = [];
    for (x = startColumn; x < endColumn; x++) {
        row.push(mapArray[y][x]);
    }
    pathfindingMapArray.push(row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a d'oh! moment when I looked at your code lol. The trick was to put pathfindingMapArray[y] = [] in the row and then the [y][x]=array bit within the x for loop.

Comment: Oh, so he creates the element automatically when passing an unused index. I'm not too familiar with Javascript, so I just googled for a push().

Comment: As I was inserting into the array at a point I decided upon, I didn't want to use .push(). However, I discovered the flaw of that is that the array is obviously still starting from 0 - so I have a series of undefined arrays followed by the ones I wanted. Maybe there is a more optimal way of doing with as somehow I still need to keep the original map xy reference.

Comment: Possibly based on [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) and mixed with [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/array_map.htm) for the extra dimension?

Comment: Yep, seems to be working. `mapArray.map(function(col){return col.slice(startCol, endCol);}).slice(startRow, endRow);`

Comment: Unfortunately, slice gives the array an entirely new index. So what was map[1] becomes map[0] after being extracted. Maybe passing only part of the map isn't the way to do this? I've got 40,000~ tiles though.

Comment: ^^ Didn't see your second post will give that a go now.

Comment: Well you could modify the pathfinding algorithm so that it also takes in the "bounds" as parameter and only processes inside that area.

Comment: That silce/map thing is just another way I thought of writing the algorithm, but it's still the same thing. I didn't realize you wanted to keep the indices! I thought you just meant a more compact way of writing it.

Comment: You know staying up at 0520am is sometimes a bad idea! I feel like a right numpty now. Ok so I've redone the algo so when it returns the waypoints to follow it just adds on the original startRow and startCol to each thus producing the correct result. And the map function I'd never heard of and is brilliant! Looks cleaner. Cheers :)

Comment: Yeah, it's 0520am over here too. :) You found a really simple solution, better than hacking at the entire algorithm! Also, be sure to run some tests on the slice/map function though, it looked okay to me when I tried it, but I might have missed some corner case. And off to bed now!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2106/discussion-between-chris-evans-and-david-gouveia)